# She comes from/of a rich family

Tags: prepositions

She is very arrogant because she comes **of/from** a rich family.

**of** is the correct preposition here. But how does using **from** here makes it grammatically wrong?

Comment: I thought **from** was correct and **of** was wrong?

Comment: Well, the word "come" is usually paired with "from" or "to". ;)

Comment: @PotatoChip My book says use of in place of from but there is no reason given.

Comment: Can you give the book info. (you should cite the source of your example anyway)? In any case, I would avoid trying to learn from a book that does not explain what it is trying to teach.

Comment: I agree with you, @user3169. There should be basis.

Comment: @shin : I think the most often "come" is paired with "on", no? Come on! :-)

Comment: @PotatoChip You are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither ***comes from*** nor ***comes of*** is wrong.

The more commonly used preposition in Modern English (for this pattern) is ***from***.
Using ***of*** makes it sound archaic.
Also note that with ***of***, the verb ***be*** was more usual<sup>1</sup> (e.g., *She is of a noble family*).

---

This [Google Ngram chart](https://goo.gl/4aKxps) shows the results of *"**comes/came of/from** a noble/rich family"*:

[image: Google Ngram chart for: comes/came of/from** a noble/rich family]

As you can see in the chart, *came **of** a noble family* was once a common phrase. It reached its peak in about 1910. The recent trend of *came/comes **from*** is obvious, particularly in the last few decades. So your book is not wrong; it just teaches you the common usage used in another century.

<sup>1</sup>Also note that although ***came of*** a noble family was once common enough, even more commonly used phrase was ***was/is of*** a noble family, as clearly shown in [this chart](https://goo.gl/m2Zq4X):

[image: a similar Google Ngram chart, but with 'was/is of a noble family' added]

I added *is/was of a noble family* to the first chart, and it dwarfed all other patterns at once. Also obvious in the chart is the fading of the trend of *"[be] of a noble family"*.

---

To wrap up this answer, *(... because) she **is/comes of** a rich/noble family* will sound **archaic**. The more usual phrasing in Modern English would be: *(... because) she **comes from** a rich family*.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'of' here describes the origin of the girl. 'From' sounds better...but grammatically... 'of' is the right preposition here as we are talking about the origin of the girl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how **of** is correct. This would be the perfect:

> "She is very arrogant because she comes from a rich family."

[*From*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/from) - Indicating the source or provenance of someone or something.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the other answers: If you want to use the word `of` in a possibly less archaic tone than `comes of` in that sentence, you can say:

> She is very arrogant because she is of a rich family.

However, this sentence is still a little archaic sounding, but I'd say not as much as using `comes of`.